# Can't store passphrase in same session with eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add

Tags: server, ssh, vps

In Ubuntu 16.04 I executed:

```
eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add
```

I got:

```
Agent pid 3361
```

I then SSH tunneled into my VPS successfully, after inserting my passphrase.

### The problem:

Well, it's not that much of a "problem", but:

I went back to my local session with `exit`, and when I tried to login to my VPS again, I had to reenter my passphrase...

### My question:

Why would I be asked to enter the passphrase again?

I didn't close the current session and did `eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add`, before tunneling. So, why the system won't "remember" it?

Comment: No comments or answers? Even with the bounty... Surprising.

Comment: I don't get this behavior, I get what you're expecting (second SSH connection authenticates without prompting for passphrase/password). Try running `ssh-add -l` before and after the working SSH connection to make sure the agent still holds the key after the first exit. Then try using `ssh -vv` (two v's) on your second attempt to connect so that the client will show you all the keys it's trying.

Comment: I find using ´ssh´ with passphrase weird to begin with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you do `eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add`, a new agent starts, so you need to re-authenticate yourself to it.

I think the best way is to store the SSH agent data permanently per session (in your `~/.profile`):

```
export SSHPROC=${HOME}/.ssh/cur-proc.${HOSTNAME}
restart_ssh_agent(){
  . ${SSHPROC}
  kill ${SSH_AGENT_PID}
  /bin/rm -rf ${SSHPROC} ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK} /tmp/ssh-*
  ssh-agent > ${SSHPROC}
  cat ${SSHPROC}
  . ${SSHPROC}
  ssh-add
}
```

and add `. ${SSHPROC}` to your `.bashrc`.

Then you call `restart_ssh_agent` once (or when it dies for some reason) and then keep your credentials with the agent.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you did here... I'm quite new to Linux. I should copy and paste this whole codeblock inside a heredoc each time I start a session?

Comment: you need to add the code which defines the function `restart_ssh_agent` to `.profile` and run it as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [detect if `ssh-agent` is already running via your `.bashrc`](https://github.com/samrocketman/home/blob/a3d29b17648e25b3ac1deb7b7a69b1a09f8e1538/dotfiles/.bashrc_custom#L89-L115).  If it is not running, then start it.  If it is already running, then use it.

Here's a snippet from my `.bashrc` which sets up environment variables for an existing session.

```
#
# setup ssh-agent
#
#start running ssh-agent if it is not already.
if [ ! 'root' = "${USER}" ]; then
  if ! pgrep ssh-agent &> /dev/null && ! uname -rms | grep Darwin &> /dev/null; then
    eval "$(ssh-agent -t 3600)" > /dev/null
  fi
  if ! uname -rms | grep Darwin &> /dev/null; then
    if [ -z "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" -o -z "${SSH_AGENT_PID}" ]; then
        #first time failed so try again.
        SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$(ls -l /tmp/ssh-*/agent.* 2> /dev/null | grep "${USER}" | awk '{print $9}' | tail -n1)"
        SSH_AGENT_PID="$(echo ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK} | cut -d. -f2)"
    fi
    if [ -z "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" -o -z "${SSH_AGENT_PID}" ]; then
      SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$(lsof -p "$(pgrep ssh-agent | tr '\n' ',')" | grep "${USER}" | grep -e "ssh-[^/]*/agent\.[0-9]\+$" | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -n1)"
      SSH_AGENT_PID="$(echo ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK} | cut -d. -f2)"
    fi
  fi
  [ -n "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" ] && export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
  [ -n "${SSH_AGENT_PID}" ] && export SSH_AGENT_PID
fi
```

I use that same snippet for multiple platforms and not just Mac or Linux on x86.  That snippet can be further improved but for now it works for me reliably.